# Content Manager not seeing default sections on items

Tags: sitecore-client, role-management, accessibility

I have two users with the same roles and the difference between them is that one can not see the default sections on all the items (Advanced, Appeareance, Help,...).

[image]

Where do I set the permissions so the other content manager can also see these sections?
He espacially needs it for the "never publish" checkbox.

Comment: Can you please add an image to your question? It looks like the image also doesn't have a description.

Answer (score 3):

The user which doesn't see default sections must check `Standard fields` in `VIEW` ribbon in Content Editor:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution

Answer (score 2):

For never publish option, as Marek mentioned you can check `Standard fields` in `VIEW` ribbon in Content Editor otherwise,

- you can click on item and then click on `Publish` --> `Change` in ribbon. Then in the `Publishing settings` pop up, select the `Item` tab and uncheck the `Publishable`.

[image]